# group concat divide two values in different table in mysql

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I would like to divide total value of table1 with value of table2 in mysql with group concate(Auto Column).

```
Manual like this: 
Select  A01-07-2013,B02-07-2013,C03-07-2013 INTO @d1,@d2,@d3 FROM Table1;
Update Table2 set Table2.A01-07-2013/@d1, 
Table2.B02-07-2013/@d2,Table2.C03-07-2013/@d3;
```

But i don't know to do like this in group concate in mysql.

In example, i have two tables as the following:

```
Table1
A01-07-2013 C02-07-2013 C03-07-2013
1000       2000       30000

Table2
A01-07-2013 B02-07-2013 C03-07-2013
100         40          50  
55          33          90
```

Coding:

```
SET @actb_pmsum = NULL;
SELECT
    GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT CONCAT(
        "sum(`",DATE_FORMAT(`currentdate`,'%d-%m-%Y'),"`) as '",
        DATE_FORMAT(`currentdate`,'%d-%m-%Y'),"'"
        )
    ) INTO @actb_pmsum
FROM tabl1;
```

Comment: would be better if you posted a sample table structure along with some demo entries, its hard to know if you table has fields named as dates ?

Comment: my table structure is date ....

Comment: please update your questions with more inputs to get faster support

Comment: please tell me in detail, i will update for u.

Comment: how does you table structure look like? what are the names of columns with your 2 tables?

Comment: As i showed u above, it is my table structure. we use crosstab convert date to column.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your table structure as

```
Table1
A01-07-2013 1000
C02-07-2013 2000
C03-07-2013 30000

Table2
A01-07-2013 100
A01-07-2013 55
B02-07-2013 40
B02-07-2013 33
C03-07-2013 50
C03-07-2013 90
```

The following should work

```
SELECT 
  table1.date,
  SUM(table1.value) / SUM(table2.value)
FROM
  table1 
  JOIN table2 ON ( table1.date = table2.date )
GROUP by
  table1.date
```

Since mysql does not have crosstab, you can then format your query as per your requirements, also note that you would probably need to do a cross join and handle no rows from either of the tables